# VBA - Listbox and Data

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I have a listbox called listbox1 that shows me the data in sheet1 but the problem is that it doesn't show me all of the data sometimes i have 3000 line of data and it shows me anlo first 50 line  this is the code i am using if someone can help please :

```
ListBox1.List = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:F3000").Value
```

Comment: The `ListBox` will only add the "A" Column data into the listbox. The ListBox entries will also be blank if there is no other data found in a perticular cell. Is there data after row 50?

Comment: yes there is data after row 50 but it doesn't show it in the listbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you need datas from one column only then you'd go:

```
ListBox1.List = Application.Transpose(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A3000")) '<== change "A"s in Range("A1:A3000") to wanted column index
```

otherwise if you want to list data from more columns you have to go like this:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim Data As Variant
...   
Data = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:F3000")
With UserForm1.ListBox1 '<== change it with actual UserForm and ListBox names
    .ColumnCount = 2
    .List = Data
End With
```

but you'd be able to select one or more (up to `ListBox` `MultiSelect` property setting) *entire* row, and not single "cells".

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the properties of the listbox to the range you need. Then change `ColumnCount` to 6.

Ie:
[image: RowSource Properties]

To make the `RowSource` dynamic, input 6 on the `ColumnCount` proterty and delete the range in the `RowSource` property and add this code to the form.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
  ListBox1.RowSource =    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:F3000").Address(external:=True)
End Sub
```

Comment: Glad I was some help.

Comment: this works _"at design time"_ (while you're writing code you also set properties) or _"before runtime"_ (opening VBA IDE and set properties before running macro). If data structure stays the same _**forever**_, then the _"at design time"_ approach could do (though I'd not recommend it). Instead, should you prefer (or need) to be more flexible and have your macro run with whatever data structure met at runtime, then you have to act as per my answer, enhanced with some criteria that checks for data structure and set listbox proprieties accordingly. Do your choice, and mark answer accordingly...

Comment: @user3598756, the poster did not ask for dynamic ranges which is why I suggested this.

Comment: @KyloRen both solutions work for non dynamic data. and Mateso wrote _"...sometimes i have 3000 line.."_, which quite stands for dynamic range...

Comment: finally i needed to work with dynamic range as you said @user3598756